# I am about to buy a new laptop to run Ubuntu. Will it boot on it? How do I check?

Tags: boot, system-installation, uefi, secure-boot

I have some questions regarding the statement below:
Ubuntu’s boot loader isn’t signed with a key that’s required by Microsoft’s certification process, but simply a key Microsoft says is “recommended.” This means that Ubuntu may not boot on all UEFI PCs. Users may have to disable Secure Boot to to use Ubuntu on some PCs.

1. I'm about to buy a new laptop to run Ubuntu. But it may not boot. How do I check it before buying?
2. What if I can't disable Secure boot?

Comment: Secure Boot and Ubuntu is fairly mature at this point.  You shouldn't have problems.  If you want a more specific answer, please edit your question and include the make and model of machine you are looking to buy.

Comment: a) take a USB stick with Ubuntu with you to try and boot it before you buy. b) The you're out of luck. Don't buy that one.

Comment: If the computer comes with Windows 8.1 or below, there will be an option in the BIOS to disable secure boot. If it comes with Windows 10 (it doesn't count if it was originally made with Windows 8), there may or may not be an option in the BIOS. In either case, however, I'm fairly certain I read that Microsoft actually does allow major Linux distros, including Ubuntu, to run on Secure Boot machines. You will most likely be fine, but the make and model of the laptop would be helpful.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I believe that's set by the OEM and not by Windows. The change to Windows 10 was that Microsoft will *allow OEMs to lock it down to a single OS* where they expressly prohibited OEMs from doing it before. Also, to the question asker, if you narrow down your list of purchases and ask then there's some chance that someone here has that same exact model (or similar enough) and can tell you if Ubuntu will work on it or not. So long as I stay in the fairly normal/atypical realm, I've had pretty good luck with hardware - especially with the Ubuntu family.